# Implementing google analytics for android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

How to Implement **Google Analytics** for the android app?

(I need basic Code I Searched a lot of Websites But I didn't understand please help me)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Here is Step by Step Explanation:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-enabling-google-analytics-to-gather-app-statistics--mobile-6607

Comment: I've seen same code in all websites like your link. can i have any example for this because i have implemented as given your link but it is not working.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I didn't get any error but if i click the button it shows nothing

Comment: How can I help you without see anything ??

Comment: If you implemented this send that code its enough

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/ 
this link will guide you.

http://dl.google.com/googleanalyticsservices/GoogleAnalyticsServicesAndroid_3.02.zip
download the jar for analytics from this link. put in in libs.

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/
and use create an account for analytics at this location. and create a new app in it. use its analytics app id as below.

and use below code in each of your activity.

```
public void TrackEvent(String category, String action, String label, Long value)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

            easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent(category, action, label, value).build());
        }

    public void onStart()
        {
            super.onStart();
            EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
            GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker(your_Analytics_ID);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();
            EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
        }
```

use trackEvent method to track your all events.

This answer is completely based on v3, but currently v4 can be used using google play services library.

**OK. here is the trick.**

create an xml file analytics.xml in values folder.

```
<resources>

<!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">google_analytics_id</string>

<!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

I hope this helps u.